# MongoDB two groups Aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

Aggregation operations process data records and return computed results. Aggregation operations group values from multiple documents together, and can perform a variety of operations on the grouped data to return a single result. MongoDB provides three ways to perform aggregation: the aggregation pipeline, the map-reduce function, and single purpose aggregation methods.

I would like to transform that :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5836b919885383034437d4a7"),
    "Identificador" : "G-3474",
    "Miembros" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5836b916885383034437d238"),
            "Nombre" : "Pilar",
            "Email" : "pcarrillocasa@gmail.es",
            "Edad" : 24,
            "País" : "España",
            "Tipo" : "Usuario individual",
            "Apellidos" : "Carrillo Casa",
            "Teléfono" : 637567234,
            "Ciudad" : "Santander",
            "Identificador" : "U-3486",
            "Información_creación" : {
                "Fecha_creación" : {
                    "Mes" : 4,
                    "Día" : 22,
                    "Año" : 2016
                },
                "Hora_creación" : {
                    "Hora" : 15,
                    "Minutos" : 34,
                    "Segundos" : 20
                }
            }
        }
}
```

into that

```
{
  "Nombre_Grupo" : "Amigo invisible"
  "Ciudades" : [
        {
          "Ciudad" : "Madrid",
          "Miembros": 30
        },
        {
          "Ciudad" : "Almería",
          "Miembros": 10
        }
        {
          "Ciudad" : "Badajoz",
          "Miembros": 20
        }
  ]

}
```

with MongoDB.

I tried with that:

```
db.Grupos_usuarios.aggregate([
   { $group: { _id: "$Nombre_Grupo",total: { $sum: "$amount" } },
 $group: { _id: "$Ciudad",total: { $sum: "$amount" } } }
])
```

but I could not get what I needed.

May somebody help me to know what I am doing bad?

Comment: Please share input collection and output collection at jsoneditor online

Comment: @MaheshBhatnagar the collection is Grupos_usuarios. It contains all this information. Thanks!!

Comment: Please share table data and what you want data at jspn editor online

Comment: Please provide a detailed document example. In given input and result, values & fields don't seem to match and are not making sense. As in the $group, you have used the "Nombre_Grupo" field which is not there in your input document. If you could provide more detailed input and the corresponding output. That would be helpful.

Comment: I posted an answer. Please tell if it is useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following aggregation gets the output you are looking for.

The [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) stage deconstructs an array field from the input documents to output a document for each element. These documents are used to group by the `Miembros.Ciudad` and get the total Miembros for each Ciudad. In the second group stage we [Pivot data](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html#pivot-data) to get all the Ciudades from the previous grouping into an array. The last `$project` is for formatting the output.

```
db.test.aggregate( [
  { 
      $unwind: "$Miembros" 
  },
  { 
      $group: { 
          _id: "$Miembros.Ciudad", 
          total: { $sum: 1 } 
      } 
  },
  { 
      $group: { 
          _id: "Amigo invisible",
          Ciudades: { $push: { Ciudad: "$_id", Miembros: "$total"} }
      } 
  },
  { 
       $project: { 
           Nombre_Grupo: "$_id", 
           Ciudades: 1, 
           _id: 0 
        } 
  } 
] )
```